# Using textscan() in Octave... How to properly format?

Tags: file-io, formatting, octave, numeric

I have a data set on disk that I'm reading line by line, and I would like to convert one of the columns of data into a vector of floats (with a range of 0-23.99999) (for that day).

The data looks something like the following:

```
2010/01/01,00:00:00.979131, 27.4485,  51.9362, 14.8,  6
2010/01/01,00:00:01.021977, 27.5149,  51.9375, 16.0,  6
2010/01/01,00:00:01.074032, 27.4797,  51.9446, 14.5, 10
2010/01/01,00:00:01.663689, 25.8441,-152.8141, 14.6,  6
2010/01/01,00:00:01.639541, 25.8744,-152.6122,  1.5,  5
2010/01/01,00:00:02.232099, -2.2447,  11.5023, 18.8,  6
2010/01/01,00:00:02.256351, -0.8135,  27.3139, 17.7,  5
2010/01/01,00:00:02.306734, -2.7797,  28.5109, 26.0,  5
2010/01/01,00:00:02.620765, 25.6656,-154.2029, 26.2,  9
2010/01/01,00:00:02.658495, 25.6698,-154.2157, 23.0,  6
2010/01/01,00:00:02.731266, -5.7106, 126.4517,  3.6,  5
2010/01/01,00:00:02.787495, -5.7138, 126.5210, 24.4,  8
2010/01/01,00:00:02.811636, -3.2453, 124.6919, 21.1,  8
```

column 2 (e.g., 00:00:00.979131) is of interest and I would like to do something like

```
setenv GNUTERM 'x11';
fid = fopen('myfile.txt', 'r');
m = textscan(fid, '%d%d%d%d/%d%d/%d%d, %d%d:%d%d:%d%f, %f, %f, %f, %d');
mx = m(:, 5); %here, I would expect to grab 14.8, 16.0, etc
my = m(:, 2) / 24.0; %here, all data from timestamp column (00:00:00.979131, for ex)
plot(mx, my);
```

The issue is that the string I pass to `textscan` is malformatted for my data.
The formatting of that number is "hrs:minutes:seconds", in military time.
How can I access/convert the values for the vars `mx`, or `my`?

Thanks,
jml

Comment: `csvread` is ill suited for this task. Try `textscan`

Comment: OK, I updated my code and question.  What am I doing wrong w/r/t textscan()'s input?

Comment: I also tried '%d/%d/%d, %d:%d:%f, %f, %f, %f, %d', to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output of `textscan` is a cell array. If you use the command in your answer:

```
m = textscan(fid, '%d/%d/%d %d:%d:%f %f %f %f %d', 'delimiter', ',');
```

Then to get a vertical vector of 14.9, 16.0, 14.5:

```
MyNinthField = m{9};

MyNinthField =
14.8000
16.0000
14.5000
14.6000
 1.5000
18.8000
17.7000
26.0000
26.2000
23.0000
 3.6000
24.4000
21.1000
```

Then, to get the timestamp (seconds since the beginning of the day):

```
Hours = double(m{4});
Minutes = double(m{5});
Seconds = m{6};
```

For `Seconds` `double` is not needed, because `m{6}` is already `double`. However, `m{4}` and `m{5}` are both `int32`.

To get the time of the day in seconds, all you need is:

```
TimeOfDayInSeconds = 3600*Hours+60*Minutes+Seconds;

TimeOfDayInSeconds =
0.97913
1.02198
1.07403
1.66369
1.63954
2.23210
2.25635
2.30673
2.62077
2.65849
2.73127
2.78749
2.81164
```

If you didn't do type conversion from `int32` to `double`, Octave would truncate the values to integers. MATLAB however does not even allow the sum between integer and double arrays.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can do something like:

```
m = textscan(fid, '%d/%d/%d %d:%d:%f %f %f %f %d', 'delimiter', ',');
```

...which, although it works, it puts the time format var that I wanted into multiple portions of a var.  Better than nothing.  If anyone has suggestions on how to concatenate those variables after, I would love to read more.  Thanks!